# Can you help me with grid-template-areas property?

Tags: css, css-grid

[image]

I want the title on top, the image on the right, and the tabs (number indicators) and the content(description) side-by-side on the left. I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried all the solution and still doesn't work. It is working on the mobile and table layout but, on the desktop layout (when is bigger than 45rem) i can't figure out how to do it.

My HTML and CSS Code:

```css
/* ------------------- */
/* Custom properties   */
/* ------------------- */

:root {
  /* colors */
  --clr-dark: 230 35% 7%;
  --clr-light: 231 77% 90%;
  --clr-white: 0 0% 100%;

  /* font-sizes */
  --fs-900: clamp(5rem, 8vw + 1rem, 9.375rem);
  --fs-800: 3.5rem;
  --fs-700: 1.5rem;
  --fs-600: 1rem;
  --fs-500: 1rem;
  --fs-400: 0.9375rem;
  --fs-300: 1rem;
  --fs-200: 0.875rem;

  /* font-families */
  --ff-serif: "Bellefair", serif;
  --ff-sans-cond: "Barlow Condensed", sans-serif;
  --ff-sans-normal: "Barlow", sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width: 35em) {
  :root {
    --fs-800: 5rem;
    --fs-700: 2.5rem;
    --fs-600: 1.5rem;
    --fs-500: 1.25rem;
    --fs-400: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 45em) {
  :root {
    /* font-sizes */
    --fs-800: 6.25rem;
    --fs-700: 3.5rem;
    --fs-600: 2rem;
    --fs-500: 1.75rem;
    --fs-400: 1.125rem;
  }
}

/* ------------------- */
/* Reset               */
/* ------------------- */

/* https://piccalil.li/blog/a-modern-css-reset/ */

/* Box sizing */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Reset margins */
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p,
figure,
picture {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* set up the body */
body {
  font-family: var(--ff-sans-normal);
  font-size: var(--fs-400);
  color: hsl(var(--clr-white));
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-dark));
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;

  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* make images easier to work with */
img,
picutre {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* make form elements easier to work with */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/* remove animations for people who've turned them off */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    animation-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    transition-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
  }
}

/* ------------------- */
/* Utility classes     */
/* ------------------- */

/* general */

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap, 1rem);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--gap, 1rem);
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

.flow > *:where(:not(:first-child)) {
  margin-top: var(--flow-space, 1rem);
}

.flow--space-small {
  --flow-space: 0.75rem;
}

.container {
  padding-inline: 2em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  max-width: 80rem;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap; /* added line */
  border: 0;
}

.skip-to-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: hsl(var(--clr-white));
  color: hsl(var(--clr-dark));
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in;
}

.skip-to-content:focus {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

/* colors */

.bg-dark {
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-dark));
}
.bg-accent {
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-light));
}
.bg-white {
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-white));
}

.text-dark {
  color: hsl(var(--clr-dark));
}
.text-accent {
  color: hsl(var(--clr-light));
}
.text-white {
  color: hsl(var(--clr-white));
}

/* typography */

.ff-serif {
  font-family: var(--ff-serif);
}
.ff-sans-cond {
  font-family: var(--ff-sans-cond);
}
.ff-sans-normal {
  font-family: var(--ff-sans-normal);
}

.letter-spacing-1 {
  letter-spacing: 4.75px;
}
.letter-spacing-2 {
  letter-spacing: 2.7px;
}
.letter-spacing-3 {
  letter-spacing: 2.35px;
}

.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fs-900 {
  font-size: var(--fs-900);
}
.fs-800 {
  font-size: var(--fs-800);
}
.fs-700 {
  font-size: var(--fs-700);
}
.fs-600 {
  font-size: var(--fs-600);
}
.fs-500 {
  font-size: var(--fs-500);
}
.fs-400 {
  font-size: var(--fs-400);
}
.fs-300 {
  font-size: var(--fs-300);
}
.fs-200 {
  font-size: var(--fs-200);
}

.fs-900,
.fs-800,
.fs-700,
.fs-600 {
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.numbered-title {
  font-family: var(--ff-sans-cond);
  font-size: var(--fs-500);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4.72px;
}

.numbered-title span {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.25);
}

/* ------------------- */
/* Compontents         */
/* ------------------- */

.large-button {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 0 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.large-button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms linear, transform 750ms ease-in-out;
}

.large-button:hover::after,
.large-button:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

/* primary-header */

.logo {
  margin: 1.5rem clamp(1.5rem, 5vw, 3.5rem);
}

.primary-header {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.primary-navigation {
  --gap: clamp(1.5rem, 5vw, 3.5rem);
  --underline-gap: 2rem;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.05);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1.5rem);
}

.primary-navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.primary-navigation a > span {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 35rem) {
  .primary-navigation {
    --underline-gap: 0.5rem;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    inset: 0 0 0 30%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: min(20rem, 15vh) 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  }

  .primary-navigation[data-visible="true"] {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .primary-navigation.underline-indicators > .active {
    border: 0;
  }

  .mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 2rem;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url(./assets/shared/icon-hamburger.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 1.5rem;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border: 0;
  }

  .mobile-nav-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
    background-image: url(./assets/shared/icon-close.svg);
  }

  .mobile-nav-toggle:focus-visible {
    outline: 5px solid white;
    outline-offset: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 35em) {
  .primary-navigation {
    padding-inline: clamp(3rem, 7vw, 7rem);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 35em) and (max-width: 44.999em) {
  .primary-navigation a > span {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 45em) {
  .primary-header::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -2.5rem;
    background: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.25);
    order: 1;
  }

  nav {
    order: 2;
  }

  .primary-navigation {
    margin-block: 2rem;
  }
}

.underline-indicators > * {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: var(--underline-gap, 0.5rem) 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.underline-indicators > *:hover,
.underline-indicators > *:focus {
  border-color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.5);
}

.underline-indicators > .active,
.underline-indicators > [aria-selected="true"] {
  color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 1);
  border-color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 1);
}

.tab-list {
  --gap: 2rem;
}

.number-indicators > button {
  border-radius: 50%;

  border: 1px solid hsl(var(--clr-white));
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: hsl(var(--clr-white));
  cursor: pointer;
}

.number-indicators > [aria-selected="true"] {
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 1);
  color: hsl(var(--clr-dark));
}

.number-indicators > *:hover {
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.5);
}

.dot-indicators > * {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.25);
}

.dot-indicators > *:hover,
.dot-indicators > *:focus {
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.5);
}

.dot-indicators > [aria-selected="true"] {
  background-color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 1);
}

/* ----------------------------- */
/* Page specific background      */
/* ----------------------------- */
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom center;
}
/* home */
.home {
  background-image: url(./assets/home/background-home-mobile.jpg);
}

@media (min-width: 35rem) {
  .home {
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(./assets/home/background-home-tablet.jpg);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 45rem) {
  .home {
    background-image: url(./assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg);
  }
}

/* destination */
.destination {
  background-image: url(./assets/destination/background-destination-mobile.jpg);
}

@media (min-width: 35rem) {
  .destination {
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(./assets/destination/background-destination-tablet.jpg);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 45rem) {
  .destination {
    background-image: url(./assets/destination/background-destination-desktop.jpg);
  }
}

/* crew */
.crew {
  background-image: url(./assets/home/background-crew-mobile.jpg);
}

@media (min-width: 35rem) {
  .crew {
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(./assets/crew/background-crew-tablet.jpg);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 45rem) {
  .crew {
    background-image: url(./assets/crew/background-crew-desktop.jpg);
  }
}

/* technology */
.technology {
  background-image: url(./assets/technology/background-technology-mobile.jpg);
}

@media (min-width: 35rem) {
  .technology {
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(./assets/technology/background-technology-tablet.jpg);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 45rem) {
  .technology {
    background-image: url(./assets/technology/background-technology-desktop.jpg);
  }
}

/* ----------------------------- */
/* Layout                        */
/* ----------------------------- */

.grid-container {
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

.grid-container p:not([class]) {
  max-width: 50ch;
}

.numbered-title {
  grid-area: title;
}

/* destination layout */

.grid-container--destination {
  --flow-space: 2rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "title"
    "image"
    "tabs"
    "content";
}

.grid-container--destination > picture {
  grid-area: image;
  max-width: 60%;
  align-self: start;
}

.grid-container--destination > .tab-list {
  grid-area: tabs;
}

.grid-container--destination > .destination-info {
  grid-area: content;
}

.destination-meta {
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top: 1px solid hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.1);
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.destination-meta p {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

/* crew layout */

.grid-container--crew {
  --flow-space: 2rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "title"
    "image"
    "tabs"
    "content";
}

.grid-container--crew > picture {
  grid-area: image;
  max-width: 60%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.1);
}

.grid-container--crew > .dot-indicators {
  grid-area: tabs;
}

.grid-container--crew > .crew-details {
  grid-area: content;
}

.crew-details h2 {
  color: hsl(var(--clr-white) / 0.5);
}

/* technology layout */
.grid-container--technology {
  grid-template-areas:
    "title"
    "image"
    "tabs"
    "content";
}

@media (min-width: 35em) {
  .numbered-title {
    justify-self: start;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }

  .destination-meta {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }

  .grid-container--crew {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    grid-template-areas:
      "title"
      "content"
      "tabs"
      "image";
  }
}

@media (min-width: 45em) {
  .grid-container {
    text-align: left;
    column-gap: var(--container-gap, 2rem);
    grid-template-columns: minmax(1rem, 1fr) repeat(2, minmax(0, 30rem)) minmax(
        1rem,
        1fr
      );
  }

  .grid-container--home {
    padding-bottom: max(6rem, 20vh);
    align-items: end;
  }

  .grid-container--home > *:first-child {
    grid-column: 2;
  }

  .grid-container--home > *:last-child {
    grid-column: 3;
  }

  .grid-container--destination {
    justify-items: start;
    align-content: start;
    grid-template-areas:
      ". title title ."
      ". image tabs ."
      ". image content .";
  }

  .grid-container--destination > picture {
    max-width: 90%;
  }

  .destination-meta {
    --gap: min(6vw, 6rem);
    justify-content: start;
  }

  .grid-container--crew {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(1rem, 1fr) minmax(0, 37rem) minmax(0, 23rem) minmax(
        1rem,
        1fr
      );
    justify-items: start;
    grid-template-areas:
      ". title title ."
      ". content image ."
      ". tabs image .";
  }

  .grid-container--technology {
    grid-template-areas:
      "title title . ."
      "tabs tabs content image"
      ". . . image";
  }

  .grid-container--technology > .number-indicators {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .grid-container--crew > picture {
    grid-column: span 2;
    align-self: end;
    max-width: 90%;
  }

  #launch-vehicle-image {
    content: url(./assets/technology/image-launch-vehicle-portrait.jpg);
  }

  #spaceport-image {
    content: url(./assets/technology/image-spaceport-portrait.jpg);
  }

  #space-capsule-image {
    content: url(./assets/technology/image-space-capsule-portrait.jpg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="navigation.js" defer></script>
    <script src="tabs.js" defer></script>
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Space tourism website</title>
  </head>
  <body class="technology">
    <a class="skip-to-content" href="#main">Skip to content</a>
    <header class="primary-header flex">
      <div>
        <img
          src="./assets/shared/logo.svg"
          alt="space tourism logo"
          class="logo"
        />
      </div>
      <button class="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-controls="primary-navigation">
        <span class="sr-only" aria-expanded="false">Menu</span>
      </button>
      <nav>
        <ul
          id="primary-navigation"
          data-visible="false"
          class="primary-navigation underline-indicators flex"
        >
          <li>
            <a
              class="ff-sans-cond uppercase text-white letter-spacing-2"
              href="index.html"
              ><span aria-hidden="true">00</span>Home</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="active">
            <a
              class="ff-sans-cond uppercase text-white letter-spacing-2"
              href="destination.html"
              ><span aria-hidden="true">01</span>Destination</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              class="ff-sans-cond uppercase text-white letter-spacing-2"
              href="crew.html"
              ><span aria-hidden="true">02</span>Crew</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              class="ff-sans-cond uppercase text-white letter-spacing-2"
              href="technology.html"
              ><span aria-hidden="true">03</span>Technology</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main id="main" class="grid-container grid-container--technology flow">
      <h1 class="numbered-title uppercase">
        <span aria-hidden="true">03</span> Space launch 101
      </h1>
      <picture id="launch-vehicle-image">
        <img
          src="assets/technology/image-launch-vehicle-landscape.jpg"
          alt="Launch vehicle image"
        />
      </picture>
      <picture id="space-capsule-image" hidden>
        <img
          src="assets/technology/image-space-capsule-landscape.jpg"
          alt="Space Capsule"
        />
      </picture>
      <picture id="spaceport-image" hidden>
        <img
          src="assets/technology/image-spaceport-landscape.jpg"
          alt="Spaceport"
        />
      </picture>

      <div
        class="number-indicators flex"
        role="tablist"
        aria-label="crew member list"
      >
        <button
          aria-selected="true"
          aria-controls="launch-tab"
          role="tab"
          data-image="launch-vehicle-image"
          tabindex="0"
        >
          <span>1</span>
        </button>
        <button
          aria-selected="false"
          aria-controls="capsule-tab"
          role="tab"
          data-image="space-capsule-image"
          tabindex="-1"
        >
          <span>2</span>
        </button>
        <button
          aria-selected="false"
          aria-controls="spaceport-tab"
          role="tab"
          data-image="spaceport-image"
          tabindex="-1"
        >
          <span>3</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-panels">
        <article
          id="launch-tab"
          class="tab-panel"
          role="tabpanel"
          tabindex="0"
          aria-hidden="false"
        >
          <header class="flow flow--space-small">
            <h2 class="fs-600 ff-serif uppercase">The terminology...</h2>
            <p class="fs-700 uppercase ff-serif">Launch vehicle</p>
          </header>
          <p class="tab-panel-text">
            A launch vehicle or carrier rocket is a rocket-propelled vehicle
            used to carry a payload from Earth's surface to space, usually to
            Earth orbit or beyond. Our WEB-X carrier rocket is the most powerful
            in operation. Standing 150 metres tall, it's quite an awe-inspiring
            sight on the launch pad!
          </p>
        </article>

        <section
          id="capsule-tab"
          class="tab-panel"
          role="tabpanel"
          tabindex="-1"
          aria-hidden="true"
          hidden
        >
          <header class="flow flow--space-small">
            <h2 class="fs-600 ff-serif uppercase">The terminology...</h2>
            <p class="fs-700 uppercase ff-serif">Space capsule</p>
          </header>
          <p class="tab-panel-text">
            The space capsule is your home away from home during your journey.
            It's equipped with state-of-the-art life support systems,
            comfortable sleeping quarters, and stunning panoramic windows for
            unparalleled views of space.
          </p>
        </section>

        <section
          id="spaceport-tab"
          class="tab-panel"
          role="tabpanel"
          tabindex="-1"
          aria-hidden="true"
          hidden
        >
          <header class="flow flow--space-small">
            <h2 class="fs-600 ff-serif uppercase">The terminology...</h2>
            <p class="fs-700 uppercase ff-serif">Spaceport</p>
          </header>
          <p class="tab-panel-text">
            A spaceport or cosmodrome is a site for launching (or receiving)
            spacecraft, by analogy to the seaport for ships or airport for
            aircraft. Based in the famous Cape Canaveral, our spaceport is
            ideally situated to take advantage of the Earth’s rotation for
            launch.
          </p>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Later Edit:

I've tried it like this and it kinda works but i want the image on the right, not on the left

```
 .grid-container--technology {
grid-template-areas:
  ". title title ."
  " image image tabs content"
  " image image tabs content";
```

}

Comment: Please include your full code (both HTML and CSS, enough to reproduce the problem), as we cannot debug images.